# How to stop the RotateAround function to rotate after Keypress in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, camera, rotation

I have a camera follow script and I am rotating the camera with Q and E key to right and left. The `Camera` is a child of a `camHolder` object. I came up with this code, which rotates around the player to the right and left, but it's shaking as it tries to keep rotating around the player.

I didn't come up with a solution to stop the `RotateAround` function, instead I tried setting `rotateSpeed` to `0` after I let go of the key, but that didn't work either.

---

```
public Transform player;
public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;
public float rotateSpeed;
private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

[SerializeField]
private Vector3 offset;

[Space]
public Transform camHolder;

void LateUpdate () 
{
    CameraFollowPlayer();
}

void Update()
{
    RotateCamera();
}

void CameraFollowPlayer()
{
    camHolder.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, player.position + offset, 
                                             ref velocity, smoothSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.LookAt(player.position);
}

void RotateCamera()
{
    if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))
    {
        rotateSpeed += 20f;
        if(rotateSpeed >= 20f)
        {
            rotateSpeed = 20f;
        transform.RotateAround(player.position, transform.up, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        rotateSpeed = 0f;
    }

    if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Q))
    {
        rotateSpeed += 20f;
        if(rotateSpeed >= 20f)
        {
            rotateSpeed = 20f;
            transform.RotateAround(player.position, transform.up, -rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        rotateSpeed = 0f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be rotating the same transform in both `Update()` and `LateUpdate()`, as they *will* conflict and you *will* see shaking / juddering, since you're telling it be one angle and then immediately you're telling it to be something else. You should probably(?) be managing the `camHolder` in one function, and the `camera` (which is `this.transform`) in the other function.

(I'm not really sure why you use `Update()` and `LateUpdate()` anyway, I would just use one.)

I'd start with this:

```
if (rotateSpeed == 0.0f)
   transform.LookAt(player.position);
```

This works fine for me:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;
    public float rotateSpeed;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 offset;

    [Space]
    public Transform camHolder;

    void Update()
    {
        RotateCamera();

        CameraFollowPlayer();
    }

    void CameraFollowPlayer()
    {
        camHolder.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, player.position + offset, 
                                                 ref velocity, smoothSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        //transform.LookAt(player.position);
    }

    void RotateCamera()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))
        {
            rotateSpeed += 20f;
            if(rotateSpeed >= 20f)
            {
                rotateSpeed = 20f;
            transform.RotateAround(player.position, transform.up, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rotateSpeed = 0f;
        }

        if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Q))
        {
            rotateSpeed += 20f;
            if(rotateSpeed >= 20f)
            {
                rotateSpeed = 20f;
                transform.RotateAround(player.position, transform.up, -rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rotateSpeed = 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I moved CameraFollowPlayer() to Update function still shaking and I tried changing transform.LookAt(player.position); to camHolder.transform.LookAt(player.position); that just changes the whole view of the focus to the player and rotates verticaly that didnt worked either. Dont know what to do now..

Comment: @Daniel Can you explain to me how your scene is laid out? Camera is under camHolder... how is player related to these?

Comment: The view should be third person, I have set an offset with which I had some problems too once because the camera wouldnt even rotate around the player on keypress it was like its locked when I would move just the camera itself around the player thats why I am moving the camHolder around the player that kinda did the rotation but now yes its shaking and there is no other relation to the player according to this infos. Okey no problem, write when you got time I try getting other things done, thanks.

Comment: @Daniel OK just meant - is player beside the `camHolder` in your Hierarchy panel? Or is it held inside something else? Or is the `camHolder` inside the player...?

Comment: No they are seperate and my Character isnt a child of anything.

Comment: @Daniel Code's in my answer, simple fix, tested it. As I said - use only `Update()`, and do not try to modify the rotation twice during the same frame. Either the script automatically controls rotation, or you control it with keys. If you are controlling, you must prevent any auto-rotate logic from running. _In future, do not give up so easily!_ This is all about try-and-try-again. You need to work at understanding code.

Comment: Okey wait I forgot to mention something, my camera has a slitly rotation on the X its viewing diagonaly to the player thats why I had the LookAt code now the camera rotates diagonaly around the player thats not what I want, do you know what I could do but beside that your code would work fine.

Comment: @Daniel I guess you're talking about camera _tilt_? What made your tilt change? It's not clear exactly what you mean there. Please clarify further  in the question, or show me a clip from a game that already does this. Or record a gif of your old code running. P.S. I would suggest you work back toward a solution from what I've given you there. You know now what you _can't_ do :)

Comment: Well I got it I watched a tutorial for Third Person Camera, but thank you!